# Regex help matching a csv styled data string with , in the data

Tags: java, regex, parsing

So I'm parsing a file and I'm writing my line strings to a CSV delimited by a `,`.  My problem is that the same line string has currency within it, which may also separated by a `,`

example:

```
84330CAX4mPWy2016112903,CAX4mPWy,2016-11-29-14.07.07.000000,CAD,$55,000.00,somename
                                                                   ^
```

Sometimes the dollar amount is less than 1000 so the `,` doesn't occur, but sometimes its higher.

I was thinking a regex where, it finds the `$` and replaces the `,` if there is more than one `\d` in front of the `$`?

Comment: replaces `,` with what?. Also show us what you've tried

Comment: try to write it! if you fail, then we will gladly help

Comment: Your CSV is simply malformed; values should be quoted out if they contain the delimiter. You need to fix this in whatever is generating the CSV to start with.

Comment: replace with "" (empty).

My attempt is terrible, i've been trying to use a regex tool online to figure it out.

(\$)(?=[\d]+[^,]*)

I'm generating the csv myself via line string and then just creating a new file with .csv

Comment: (\$)[\d]+(,) matches the expression, but I need to replace the "," this matches everything including the ","

Comment: @TaranjitKang - Edit your question to add your attempt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use positive lookahead for one or more digits preceeded by one non-digit,one or more digits and a comma.
This will work for you:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    String s = "84330CAX4mPWy2016112903,CAX4mPWy,2016-11-29-14.07.07.000000,CAD,$55,000.00,somename";
    System.out.println(s.replaceAll("(\\D\\d+),(?=\\d+)", "$1"));
}
```

O/P :

```
84330CAX4mPWy2016112903,CAX4mPWy,2016-11-29-14.07.07.000000,CAD,$55000.00,somename
```

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I was looking for, I was going about it all wrong starting with $ first. I have to look into the $1 and matching occurence. Would thumbs up if I could.

Comment: @TaranjitKang you can't upvote, but you can still [accept this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if it is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The approach to do that depends on your needs.

I would group the values:

```
private static final String STRING_TO_PARSE = "84330CAX4mPWy2016112903,CAX4mPWy,2016-11-29-14.07.07.000000,CAD,$55,000.00,somename";
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(.+),(.+),(.+),(.+),(\\$[\\d,]+\\.\\d\\d),(.+)").matcher(STRING_TO_PARSE);
    matcher.find();
    for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(i));
    }
}
```

Comment: I will try that and look into matcher, I need the whole line string pretty much but without the "," in the $ amount

Comment: Hey thanks, i never even knew about this -- learning regex still -- I was about to change to fit my needs! thank you, going to look more into this for other stuff.